# Return Array of Objects/Hashes sorted by attributes

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, attributes, unique

I have an array of objects, in this example represented as hashes:

```
[
 { "mid" => 123, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:05"}
 { "mid" => 456, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:06:05"}
 { "mid" => 789, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:05"}
 { "mid" => 123, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:07"}
 { "mid" => 456, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:05"}
]
```

And I need to get back only elements with the unique mid, in a process of selecting unique objects, timestamp needs to be taken to consideration, where higher datetime is the one to return. So my examples outcome would be:

```
[
 { "mid" => 456, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:06:05"}
 { "mid" => 789, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:05"}
 { "mid" => 123, "updated" => "2015-05-05 05:05:07"}
]
```

I tried couple of different approaches, but I have a problem with my logic, I always get 20 objects back instead of 3. Here is my code:

```
res = []
queue.length.times do
    a = queue.pop
    queue.each do |job|
        if a.mid == job.mid
            if DateTime.parse(a.updated) >= DateTime.parse(a.updated)
                res << a
            end
        else
            res << a
        end
    end
    queue << a
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hash you have posted is not valid. Please post the correct hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your input in `arr`:

```
arr.group_by do |h| 
  h['mid']                   # group same mids
end.values.map do |all|
  all.max_by do |h|
    Date.parse h['updated']  # pick latest by date
  end
end

#⇒ [
#    {"mid"=>123, "updated"=>"2015-05-05 05:05:07"},
#    {"mid"=>456, "updated"=>"2015-05-05 05:06:05"},
#    {"mid"=>789, "updated"=>"2015-05-05 05:05:05"}
# ]
```

Please avoid writing phpish code using ruby syntax.

**UPD** Credits to Cary Swoveland, `sort_by+last` reduced to `max_by`.

Comment: Returns only one object/hash.

Comment: Exactly as you requested.

Comment: No, you must have misunderstood, like I said my outcome in this example wold be three hashes/objects. You can see expected outcome in my question. Sorry if my explanation didn't make that clear, english is a second language for me.

Comment: Go give it a try. It returns exactly the result you requested.

Comment: Consider [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) rather than sorting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like:

```
queue.sort_by { |r| DateTime.parse(r[:updated]) }.reverse.uniq { |r| r[:mid] }

# => [{:mid=>456, :updated=>"2015-05-05 05:06:05"}, {:mid=>123, :updated=>"2015-05-05 05:05:07"}, {:mid=>789, :updated=>"2015-05-05 05:05:05"}]
```

where `queue` is your input array.

Comment: That produces only one object/hash.

Comment: Apparently not every hash has an indirect access. _Hint_: OP has string keys.

Comment: If your hash objects in the array don't have symbol keys, use strings, but the code should work.